# Make GameObject hover above a plane? - Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make an FPS-type game and is it possible to have a GameObject locked on the Y-axis/not able to move up or down? The GameObject is a model of an AWP from Counter Strike, I am making it move around the plane with the WASD keys, and when I use the mouse to look up/down, the AWP goes diagonally to where I'm looking, and I don't want that. My game looks like this: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5uGL.jpg)

Here's the code I have for the AWP if it helps:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class AWPscript : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed = 5f;
// public float sensitivityX = 15.0f;
// public float sensitivityY = 15.0f;
public Camera MainCamera;
public Camera scopeCamera;
public float lookSensitivity = 10f;
public float xRotation ;
public float yRotation ;
public float currentXRotation;
public float currentYRotation;
public float xRotationV;
public float yRotationV;
public GameObject Scopepng;
public float lookSmoothDamp = 0.1f;
public Image ScopePNG;
public AudioClip sound;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    speed = 7.5f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime*speed);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        speed = 15f;



    lookAround();
     scope();
}

void scope()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {

        MainCamera.enabled = false;
        scopeCamera.enabled = true;
        ScopePNG.enabled = true;

    }
    else
    {

        MainCamera.enabled = true;
        scopeCamera.enabled = false;
        ScopePNG.enabled = false;

    }
}
void lookAround()
{
    xRotation -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSensitivity;
    yRotation += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSensitivity;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
}
}
```

Comment: "scope" should be "Scope", not "scope".

Comment: Juan, look carefully at the INSPECTOR for rigidbody.  you will see the answer!

Comment: @JoeBlow Checking the "Freeze Position [Y]" doesn't work for some reason :/

Comment: ah, you're moving the thing "BY HAND" rather than letting the physics engine do it (applying forces)

Comment: @JoeBlow Yep, I'm rotating the object with the mouse and using the WASD keys to move it forward, backward, left and right. So is there any way to freeze the Y position still?

Comment: sure, simple I'll put in an answer.  PS could you edit the code you include, Juan, and include the name of the class.  for some reason fokls often do that, chop of the top of the file!  it's very confusing and makes it hard to refer to it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's probably the simplest solution:

```
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime*speed);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        speed = 15f;

    LookAround();
    Scope();

    JoeFix();
    }

public float fixedFloatingHeightMeters; // set to say 1.4 in the editor
private void JoeFix()
   {
   Vector3 p = transform.position;
   p.y = fixedFloatingHeightMeters;
   transform.position = p;
   }
```

**PS!** you really MUST rename lookAround to LookAround and scope to Scope. It can affect things later

---

Here's kind of an advanced piece of information that may be more what you want. Please try this also!

Currently you have a vector that is the NOSE OF THE OBJECT pointing.

Say the thing is heading NORTH, ok?

So, [transform.forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) is pointing North BUT, IT IS POINTING "DOWN A BIT".

Although it is pointing north, if you saw it from the side that vector is pointing DOWN A BIT.

What you really want is that vector, but FLAT, NOT POINTING DOWN OR UP. Right?!

In fact here's the magic to do that:

```
Vector3 correctDirectionButPossiblyDownOrUp = transform.forward;
Vector3 correctDirectionButFlatNoDownOrUp;
correctDirectionButFlatNoDownOrUp
 = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(
     correctDirectionButPossiblyDownOrUp,
     Vector3.up );
correctDirectionButFlatNoDownOrUp.Normalize();
```

**correctDirectionButFlatNoDownOrUp** is now the "magic" vector you want.

But, don't forget Translate works in LOCAL SPACE. (the "object's" idea of the world.)  You very much want to move it in world space, which is easy. Notice the last argument: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

```
transform.Translate(
    correctDirectionButFlatNoDownOrUp * Time.deltaTime*speed,
    Space.World);
```

So that's it !

*footnote* Don't forget "Vector3.up" has absolutely no connection to "Vector3".

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly what I needed. And I did as you asked, those two functions are now renamed. Enjoy your day :)

Comment: @JuanFranciscoPatino i put in a further anwser which may help.  Cheers

Comment: Nice, Should I replace the contents of Joefix(); with that to try it out?

Comment: On worries - I would just press on, and keep it as useful knowledge for another day!!  A really key thing is to get that Translate works LOCALLY (unless you specify World) ... everyone gets tripped up on that!  it's ridiculous Unity didn't simply do TranslateLocally and TranslateWorld so it is clear.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't need the gravity then removing the RigidBody component will stop Unity applying gravity and it will hover.

Comment: I should've worded it better, I meant to say something like how can I make it so the gameobject can't move on the Y axis? I'll edit the question right now.

Comment: Oh, then you can either set a constraint on the Y Axis or set UseGravity to false. Whichever best meets your requirements.

Comment: When I use gravity the AWP just falls down, what do you mean by setting a constraint on the Y-axis? I'm pretty new to Unity, started two days ago. Check my edited question, I added more detail.

Comment: If you look at your RigidBody component you should see a Constraints option, click that and you should have the option to freeze the Y Axis.

What do you mean by falls down? Do you mean to the ground or following your view? As your question seems to say both.

Comment: I'm really tired but I'll try my best to explain: When I turn gravity on, the AWP simply falls to the ground, but when I turn gravity off, the AWP moves to where I'm looking when I move forward with the "W" key, whether I'm looking up or down, it would still move to wherever I'm looking at. I want to simulate walking in games like counter-strike and Call of Duty. Hope that made sense. By the way, the Constraints thing didn't work :(

Comment: I think your problem is in the implementation itself. You should really have a character that you control and your gun is then added to the character. if you look for the Character Controller in Unity Standard Assets (Google) you'll find a working First Person Controller.

I'd then recommend looking into adding a gun to the controller rather than trying to control the gun.

Comment: It says if I use it, it will change my project settings, what will that do? Should I carry on with the download?

Comment: Jordan, this is irrelevant - OP is moving it kinematically, nothing to do with physics it turns out

Comment: My bad, was a little hard to piece it together without Unity in front of me. Thought I'd at least point Juan in the direction of a character controller rather than controlling a gun.